# Pass EF context on a project with multiple layers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have an application that is separated into 4 layers to keep code organized and be able to reuse it.

My layers are:

- presentation layer: an mvc4 project
- business layer: a c# library project whit the Business logic
- Data layer: a c# library that contains all the linq to the db
- model layer: a c# library that contains a edmx ef5 for my database

So the idea is that for each controller or our mvc project we have 1 business class and 1 data class. and if some functionality needs to make use of code on other class, they do at business logic layer (different business logic classes can create new instances of other business logic classes.)

The problem I was having is that I was creating too many `DbContext` and I was getting some errors and problems because of it. Like loosing the lazy loading on my BL layers or not been able to assign objects like list to other objects when they came from different `DbContext`.

For example, if I have a medic controller/logic/data and I use a patient logic/data to get a list of patient for today, I get an error when I try to do `medic.patients = patienstList;`

So what I need to do is use one `DbContext` per web request, so the `DbContext` will be created on the controller and injected to the logic layer and those will inject to other logic class or to the data classes?

How can I do it?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use an IoC framework which creates an `DbContext` for the lifetime of a web request and passes this as a constructor parameter in the classes who need it.

Comment: FWIW, relying on lazy-loading is a good way to hammer your database. If you need a related object(s), the include them in your initial query and query once for all. Otherwise, you end up with hidden database calls that happen at all kinds of points in your request cycle, depending on when you finally try to access the data. It's better to be explicit about what data you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways of doing IOC in MVC.
Example would Unity.. where you can register an instance of DBContext.

Of course if the lifetime of you IOC container every extends beyond web requests. your are in for nasty time.
Even if you think it is 1 Context per request that you need. Be very careful if you use ASP pipeline events and access DbContext, you may actually need 1 context per Thread.  But if you are happy to say you access starts at MVC Controller level. Then you are looking for a way to handle inversion of control only.

[Unity from microsoft](https://unity.codeplex.com/)

dependency injection docu
https://unity.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the Business Object should not have to use another Business Object because that violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

The Data Layer object should be able to do everything the Business Object needs it to.

So you should write methods in the Business Layer Object and Data Layer Object method GetPatientsForMedic.

You may say "but the Hospitals Business Object can get me a list of Hospitals really easily". That is not it's job, because you said it's job is to service the Hospitals controller.

HOWEVER the problem only happens when you pass a Hospital object from the HospitalsBO to the MedicBO. So don't.

On the Hospitals controller, write a method GetListOfHospitalIDsAndNames. Then, if you need a dropdown of hospitals, call that, and use the IDs and text names.

You can indeed share a DbContext between two Business Objects by sharing a Unit of Work. But you probably shouldn't.

However i'm no expert... i avoided these problems by having one GINORMOUS business object with everything in it. That is also a BAD THING.